# AngularJS 4.0 / TFS - TFS not allowed to checkin $data folder

Tags: c#, angular, tfs

I am writing a code in AngularJS 4.0. We are using TFS as source code management tool.

We have

> $data.js

file added in our project. But TFS is not allowed us to check-in this file.

I am getting below message -

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
>   --------------------------- Add to Source Control
>
> No eligible items were found for addition.
>
> ### --------------------------- OK   Help

Please help me in resolving this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the exception is correct.  Please take a look at official [Naming Syntax, Conventions, and Limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245472(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Most names in Team Foundation version control cannot begin or end with spaces or tabs. Any character can be used for names or labels, except
>
> ...
>
> **A dollar sign ($) cannot be the first character in a file name.**

You cannot place files with those names in TFVC. Otherwise you may get a similar error as below:

> *TF10122: The path ‘$/xx/$data.js’ contains a ‘$’ at the beginning of a path component. Remove the ‘$’ and try again.”*

You have to **rename** this file `$data.js` to another name syntax then check in TFS again.